# Why does writing to binary file writes one byte from no where

Tags: c++, binary, bin

I have a class for writing to bytes to binary file

```
class BITWRITER{
public:
ofstream OFD;
char var;
int x;
BITWRITER(char* pot){
    OFD.open(pot);
    x = 0;
    var  =0;

}
void WRITE(bool b){
    var ^= (-b^var)&(1 << x);
    x++;
    if(x == 7){
        OFD.write(&var, 1);
        x = 0;
        var = 0;
    }

}
}
```

And my sample code:

```
string bitCode = "0001010";
bool BitIsOne = false;
BITWRITER *write= new BITWRITER("out.bin");
for(int i =  bitCode.length()-1 ; i >= 0; i--){
    if(bitCode[i] == '1')
            BitIsOne=true;
        else
            BitIsOne=false;
    write->WRITE(BitIsOne);
}
delete write;
```

What I don't get it is, why when i run this exact code,  when I then next read this file instead of having in binary file only one byte, I have two bytes.

In this example, the output should be 
"1010"
but before this one random byte is somehow created ("1101").

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the type of `var` and what is the `sizeof(var)`?

Comment: var is _char_ . And size is 1 byte as normal char.

Comment: what's initial value of var and x?

Comment: Updated the class above. I noticed that this is only a case, when I want to write certain bits. Looked in the ASCII table, does "\n" need "\r" or something so it generates automatically? Because 1010 is "\n" and 1101 is "\r" in ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary `1010` is `0x0a` which is a newline.  You're openign the file without specifying that it should be opened in binary mode.

On Windows when you write a newline to a text mode file it will translate it to a cr/lf sequence.  A cr return is 0x0d which is a binary `1101`.

Specify that the file should be opened in binary mode:

```
OFD.open(pot, ios::binary);
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver, should have asked you 3 hours ago. !

Comment: Well, I was asleep 3 hours before I wrote the answer! :)  From your comment above, it looks like you were pretty much on track for figuring it out yourself.